# Missing required parameter for [Route: one_one.update] [URI: one_one/{one_one}] [Missing parameter: one_one]

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am getting error at {{ route('one_one.update',$student->id) }} and I am unable to use edit for CRUD operation because of this error.

Route (I am using resource controller so my route is this)

```
Route::resource('/one_one',StudentController::class);
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('one_one.update',$student->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        Name <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $student->name }}"><br><br>
        Contact <input type="text" name="contact" value="{{ $student->contact }}"><br><br>
        Email <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ $student->email }}"><br><br>
    <h3>Student Details</h3>
        Alternative contact <input type="text" name="alter_contact" value="{{ $student->studentdetail->alter_contact }}"><br><br>
        Address <input type="text" name="address" value="{{ $student->studentdetail->address }}"><br><br>
        Course <input type="text" name="course" value="{{ $student->studentdetail->course }}"><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

index.balde.php

```
<form action="{{ route('one_one.edit',$student->id) }}"><button type="submit">Edit</button></form>
                <form action="{{ route('one_one.destroy',$student->id) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit">Delete</button></form>
```

Controller

```
public function edit(Student $student)
    {
        return view('one_one.edit',compact('student'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, Student $student)
    {
        $student=Student::update([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'contact'=>$request->contact,
            'email'=>$request->email,
        ]);

        $student->studentdetail()->update([
            'alter_contact'=>$request->alter_contact,
            'address'=>$request->address,
            'course'=>$request->course,
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('one_one.index')->with('success','Data updated successfully');
    }
```

I also tried to pass $student->id as array but it is also not working.

Comment: [You need to pass `one_one` as a key/value pair](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)

Comment: Can you show how you passed it as a key/value?

Comment: ["one_one"=>"$student->id"] Here please take a look

Comment: `{{ route('one_one.edit', ["one_one"=>$student->id]) }}` should work, if that's the parameter it's complaining about.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Tried this before posting the question also

Comment: Can you show an entire error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an empty non-existing model to your view. There is no Implicit Route Model Binding happening for your `edit` method. The route parameter name is not matching the typehinted parameter of the Controller's `edit` method. You are getting method injection (a new instance of a `Student` model) instead of Implicit Route Model Binding

Your route parameter for your resource routes is `one_one`(as that is the name of the resource) not `student`. Your method signature would have to be adjusted for Implicit Route Model Binding:

```
public function edit(Student $one_one)
```

[Laravel 10.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#implicit-binding)

Comment: Thanks as it worked for me but can you explain why it will take $one_one in resource controller as I have not declared any varaible like $one_one before in the controller. so why does it take that in edit method of resource controller ? Also I checked by dd($student) in previous method of controller and its working fine there. So why does it take $one_one for edit method.

Comment: @PranavSompura well, your `update` method isn't actually doing what you think ... your `student` argument is being overwritten on the first line of the method and `$student` would be a 'int' after that ... not sure what methods you are talking about that are working currently ... but the reason you have to make that adjustment is "Implicit Route Model Binding" which is linked in the answer